# How to invoke ShutdownHook thread with a window close operation of DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE or EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Tags: java, multithreading, process

Assuming that `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()` has been set up correctly, how can the ShutdownHook thread be invoked when a Java application window (`JFrame`) is closed (in this case the only window) and the dispose window default close operation is `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` or `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`?

Note that for a quit command handled with a `System.exit(0)` which is then fed through the ShutdownHook thread, the application terminates correctly as all the associated threads are terminated before the Java application exits. So I want to accomplish the same thing by making the closing of the `JFrame` window go through the ShutdownHook thread clean up.

Comment: Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. EXIT_ON_CLOSE and DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE both ulimately invoke System.exit(), so don't understand the difference between "a QUIT command" (whatever that is) and the close operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works according to your spec.  If I close the frame by clicking the `X` button, the shutdown hook is invoked.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class ShutDownHookDemo {

    public static void endMessage() {
        // clean up threads here..
        System.out.println("Thanks for using the app.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                endMessage();
            }
        };
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(t);

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300,300);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, so there is obviously something else going on in the mix. I also ran your code with `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` and it worked the same (bar a slight delay in printing out the debug message while clean up was handled a bit more gracefully).

Answer (score 2):

`frame.addWindowListener()` and override `windowClosed(WindowEvent e)`. From your question it looks you just need an event handling when the window gets closed.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...);
```

Comment: I already do this. I have revised my question as it was not clear enough.